# I need to make the port number a variable that can be added from a dialog box in Vite js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js, vuejs3, vite

I need to make the port number a variable that can be changed when a user enters the port number in a dialog box. So I already have a port number in here which it is 3080. I will have to make a dialog box or a modal in my front end that asks the user if they would like to change the port number in which it is running. This user will then be able to change the port number by the click of a button. I am using Vue 3 with Vite. But I cannot make this port number a state that can be changed. Does anyone know what to do?
Thank you to anyone reading this! Here is my vite.config.js file

```
import { defineConfig, loadEnv } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

export default defineConfig(({mode})=>{
const env = loadEnv(mode, process.cwd());

return{
plugins: [vue()],
build:{
   outDir:"./wwwroot/app/", sourcemap:true
},
server: {
proxy: {
  "^/api": {
    target:env.VITE_PORT,
    changeOrigin: true,
    secure: false,
    withCredentials: true,
    rewrite: (path) => path.replace(/^\/api/, ``),
    },
   },
   port:3080
   },
  }
 })
```

This is my main.js file

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import VueApexCharts from "vue3-apexcharts";
import router from './router';
import App from './App.vue'
import store from './store';
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/all';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import ElementPlus from 'element-plus'
import 'element-plus/dist/index.css'
import vClickOutside from "click-outside-vue3"
const app=createApp(App)
app.use(VueApexCharts);
app.use(router)
app.use(ElementPlus)
app.use(store)
app.use(vClickOutside)
app.mount('#app')
```

Comment: `This user will then be able to change the port number by the click of a button` - do you envisage this happening in the vue app while running in dev mode? Do you understand the `server: { proxy` setting is for development mode? i.e. when running the `dev` script

Comment: Do I have to make it in a production mode to create a port variable like that/

Comment: In production you use your own server

Comment: Than I am using my own server. Is it possible to make the port changeable as per the requirements of the user with the click of a button?

Comment: not by changing `vite.config.js` - since that won't exist on production

Comment: Thank you!! I am stuck on something with no solution I can think of right now. But thanks for the discussion